# Is Django, is queryset's filter and relation manager same thing?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

In my views.py, I want to have a queryset of all the competitions of this client, and I use related_name in the client field of competition
I think I have two ways:
suppose these two models are imported in views.py
1.`resultSet=Competition.objects.filter(host=client)`
2.`resultSet=client.myCompetition`

I have 2 issues:

1) In my view.py, I actually try to do the second way, I wrote: `client0=request.user.client_profile`, and django says django related not exist.

2) I am wondering how is relations manager implemented in Django, is it 
1))some pointers stored in relations manager, so it can access the data more quickly 
or 
2))have scan the database and basically same as "filter"?

I am using mysql.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django each model class has a manager instance, `objects`, which methods usually returns a QuerySet instance (not all manager's methods return a QuerySet though). The QuerySet is a lazy object responsible to create a query (SQL) to send to the underlying database when you actually request the data. So the Manager is just an helper to initialize the correct QuerySet.

About a related field, the mechanic works just the same, instead of having an helper associated to a Model, you have an helper associated to a ModelField. The point is always to get a QuerySet in the end.

Using one or the other is usually a meter of taste (maybe code readability) as long as the semantic is the same, but if you are concerned about performance, you can always inspect what the resulting QuerySet would actually issue to the database by printing

```
print my_query_set.query
```

And you'll have the SQL that will be sent to the db as soon as you try to access data.